# filtrar una lista con multiples checkbox en Angular 6

Tags: angular

tengo un arreglo de restaurantes

```
 restaurants=[
{ restname: "rest1", isDelivery: true, isItalian:false, isBreakfast:true},
{ restname: "rest2", isDelivery: false, isItalian:true, isBreakfast:true},
{ restname: "rest3", isDelivery: true, isItalian:false,isBreakfast:false}]
```

y los muestro con un *ngFor de la siguiente manera:

```
 <div *ngFor="let rest of restaurants" >
 <p> {{rest.restname}} <p>
```

y tengo una lista de checkbox que incluyen las categorias por las cuales se pueden filtrar los restaurantes:

```
 <p *ngFor="let cat of categories">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cat.checked" > {{cat.cat}}
</p>
```

.ts

```
 categories=[
{ cat: "Delivery", checked: false},
{ cat: "Italian Food", checked: false},
{ cat: "Breakfast Service", checked: false}]
```

me gustaría saber como podría hacer un pipe(si es la mejor manera) o algo para filtrar la lista de restaurantes por el o los checkbox que seleccione, por ejemplo seleccione delivery e italian food y me muestre restaurante 1 y restaurante 2?